# How to insure integrity in data sent to my database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, post, get

I have a post api that sends data to my DB, some of the value are passed by a get api using frontend.
How can I make sure the user did not change the data?
would using cookies or cache be save and optimal?
some data needs to be there (like the field ID) and should not be modified, and I can't get it except from the get request.

Comment: Like.. fetch the original from the database and doing some validation before persisting it? Is that your question?

Comment: lets assume I'm using "getUsername" with the field (Id, firstName, lastName), Id should not be changed. then I have my"postUsername" where the user can update(firstName, lastName), in order for this request to happen I need to provide the Id. How can I make sure the Id in the get and post functions are the same and not changed by the user(by Burpsuite or other methods)?

Comment: "How can I make sure the Id in the get and post functions are the same". You don't. You simply update the user with the ID that was passed in the post if it exists. If the ID changes to something entirely new (unexisting userId), then perhaps you can create another user from it or return a bad request.

Answer (score 0):

In no where is it said that your database model, your business objects model, your API model and your frontend mode have to be exactly the same. For example you may have a database table `User` with fields `id`, `email`, `postal_address` and `password`, you may have business logic objects `User` with fields `id`, `email` and `postal_address` and `UserPasswordUpdateCommand` with fields `id`, `oldPassword` and `newPassword`. You may have API model `ChangeUserPasswordModel` with `email`, `oldPassword` and `newPassword` and frontend model with something else. And all this would interact with the same database table `User` through different business logic use cases. Each one would have their own validations and controls so therefor you would never change something you don't want to change.

Comment: lets assume I'm using "getUsername" with the field (Id, firstName, lastName), Id should not be changed. then I have my"postUsername" where the user can update(firstName, lastName), in order for this request to happen I need to provide the Id. How can I make sure the Id in the get and post functions are the same and not changed by the user(by Burpsuite or other methods)?

Comment: Let's say the ID is changed. So what? If user has privileges to change the object with the other ID then he should be allowed to change it. If not, then you should check as on your backend if user who posted the change actually has the privileges to change this object. If you are concerned that user wanted to change object A, but man in the middle hijacked the request so that object B would be changed instead (without the user knowing) then that's what HTTPS is for.

Comment: And if the question is, how do you know that who the user is who posted the request then that's what sessions or authentication tokens are for. Auth tokens for example are signed by backend and cannot be modified by man in the middle.